# Does python have a magic function that formats a arbitrarily formatted date into a standard form?

Tags: python, date

I have a little application that returns several dates. However, some are formatted different than others. I need to built a function that 1.) guess/detect the current form, 2.) convert date tostandard form. Does python already have something like that in place?

Comment: Use `dateutil.parser` to parse arbitrary date formats. You then have a `datetime` object, which can be formatted back to a string with ease.

Comment: @MartijnPieters done and done